# Is there a way to execute JavaScript in Perl?

Tags: javascript, perl

I've worked some years now in Perl building Web scrapers, and given the problem that spam represents, and how scraping Web pages would turn out to be much more easier to those folks if, for example, Perl's [LWP::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent) could handle its cup of JavaScript, I'm amazed no one has built a JS engine for it yet.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance. Regards.

PS: I'm not a spammer. Just curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would you mean something like [JavaScript::SpiderMonkey](http://p3rl.org/JavaScript::SpiderMonkey), a Perl interface to a JavaScript engine used by Mozilla?

Answer (score 6):

[`WWW::Selenium`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aWWW%3a%3aSelenium)?

Answer (score 6):

[TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMTOWTDI).
Another option is [WWW::Scripter](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aScripter), with the Javascript or AJAX plugin.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [Win32::IE::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aIE%3a%3aMechanize), [Mozilla::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mozilla%3a%3aMechanize). But the previously mentioned [WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aSelenium) is the most DWIW and well-supported *if* you have access to browsers and can run the Selenium server. [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a Java critter that runs the browser interactions for you. It has [IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)s for several browsers and can write code for you—by recording browser actions—in [several languages](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#programming-languages) including Perl or you can hand write it. It’s [test-centric](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aWWW%3a%3aSelenium), where it excels, but there is no reason not to be use it for general automation/scraping.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to install SpiderMonkey and -in your perl program-  execute javascript in backticks, and capture the result, just like from any other unix command line tool. Spidermonkey has a command line option for that, similar to perl's -e command line option. The spidermonkey binary is called "js", thus:

> /path/to/spidermonkey/bin/js -e "print(10);"
>
> > 10

I think you can also install v8-shell as an alternative engine, but then you must install 'scons' first, which is available on unix-only.

> ./v8-shell -e 'print("10*10 = " + 10*10)'